# CSS issue - I want the client area totally filled

Tags: jquery, css, sliding, panels

I really struggle with CSS. I am trying mod a sliding door technique that opens onto a full-client area div, but I just cannot get the full client area filled up. I am modding from here:

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/sliding-door-effect-with-jquery/

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<style type='text/css'>    
    .box_container{
        position:relative; /* important */
        width:100%; /* we must set a specific width of the container, so it doesn't strech when the image starts moving */
        height:100%; /* important */
        /*min-width: 100%;*/
        /*min-height: 100%;*/
        overflow:hidden; /* hide the content that goes out of the div */
        /*just styling bellow*/
        background: black;
        color:white;
    }
    .images_holder
    {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position:absolute; /* this is important, so the div is positioned on top of the text */
    }
    .image_div {
        position:relative; /* important so we can work with the left or right indent */
        overflow:hidden; /* hide the content outside the div (this is how we will hide the part of the image) */
        width:50%; /* make it 50% of the whole images_holder */
        height: 100%;
        float:left; /* make then inline */
    }
    .right img{
        margin-left: -100%; /* 100% is in this case 50% of the image, so this is how we show the second part of the image */
    }
    .clear{
        clear:both;    
    }
</style>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var cv, box, holder, cvContext, width, height, my_gradient, boxHeight, boxWidth;

        //        box = document.getElementById("box");
        //        boxWidth = box.offsetWidth;
        //        boxHeight = box.offsetHeight;

        //        holder = document.getElementById("imageHolder");
        //        holder.width = boxWidth;
        //        holder.hieght = boxHeight;

        box = document.getElementById("box");
        //$("box").css({ width: $(window).width(), height: $(window).height() });
        $("box").css({ width: window.innerWidth, height: window.innerHeight });
        $("imageHolder").css({ 'min-width': window.innerWidth, 'min-height': window.innerHeight });

        cv = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        width = cv.width;
        height = cv.height;
        cvContext = cv.getContext("2d");
        my_gradient = cvContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, height);
        my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "blue");
        my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
        cvContext.fillStyle = my_gradient;
        cvContext.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        cv = document.getElementById("canvas2");
        width = cv.width;
        height = cv.height;
        cvContext = cv.getContext("2d");
        my_gradient = cvContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, width, height);
        my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "blue");
        my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
        cvContext.fillStyle = my_gradient;
        cvContext.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        //when the user hovers over the div that contains our html...
        $('.box_container').hover(function () {
            //... we get the width of the div and split it by 2  ...
            var width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;
            /*... and using that width we move the left "part" of the image to left and right "part"
            to right by changing it's indent from left side or right side... */
            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right: width }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left: width }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
        }, function () {
            //... and when he hovers out we get the images back to their's starting position using the same function... '
            $(this).find('.left').animate({ right: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            $(this).find('.right').animate({ left: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            //... close it and that's it
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<!--START THE MAIN CONTAINER-->
<div id="box" class='box_container'>

        <!--START THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->
        <div id="imageHolder" class='images_holder'>

            <!--INSERT THE SAME IMAGE IN 2 DIVS, THEY BOTH HAVE image_div CLASS AND left OR right CLASS DEPENDING ON POSITION-->
            <div class='image_div left'><canvas id="canvas1" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></div>
            <div class='image_div right'><canvas id="canvas2" style="width:100%; height:100%;"/></div>

            <!-- WE USED CSS FLOAT PROPERY, SO WE NEED TO CLEAR NOW-->
            <div class='clear'></div>

        </div>
        <!--END THE IMAGE PARTS HOLDER-->

        <!--START THE TEXT-->
        The text underneath
        <!--END THE TEXT-->
</div>
<!--END THE MAIN CONTAINER-->  

</body>
</html>
```

Instead of the small thin strip, how can I get the panels covering the entire client area of the screen?

---

OK, I have tried to simplify, and remove all css, so everything is done in code behind. I am using the viewport as suggested. But nothing seems to work. In fact it does not even recognise the hover anymore.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I seem to change any widths, heights etc onload? Why has my hover stopped working?

Please help.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--Note this doctype is essential to recognise canvas-->
<html>
<head>
<title>Dual sliding door effect with one Image</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function MyOnLoad() {
        var cvContext, my_gradient;
        var width, height, widthWin, heightWin, widthDoc, heightDoc, widthMain;
        var divBox = document.getElementById('divBox');
        var divHolder = document.getElementById("divHolder");
        var divUnderneath = document.getElementById("divUnderneath");
        var divDoorLeft = document.getElementById("divDoorLeft");
        var divDoorRight = document.getElementById("divDoorRight");
        var canvas1 = document.getElementById("canvas1");
        var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");

        widthWin = $(window).width();   // returns width of browser viewport
        heightWin = $(window).height();   // returns width of browser viewport
        widthDoc = $(document).width(); // returns width of HTML document
        heightDoc = $(document).height(); // returns width of HTML document

        width = widthWin;
        height = heightWin;

        divBox.style.width = width;
        divBox.style.height = height;
        divBox.style.background = "#AAFFAA";
        divBox.style.position = "relative";
        divBox.style.overflow = "hidden";
        divBox.style.color  = "#FFFFFF";

        divHolder.style.width = width;
        divHolder.style.height = height;
        divHolder.style.background = "#AAAAFF";
        divHolder.style.position = "absolute";

        divUnderneath.style.width = width;
        divUnderneath.style.height = height;
        divUnderneath.style.background = "#FFAAAA";

        divDoorLeft.style.position = "relative";
        divDoorLeft.style.overflow = "hidden";
        divDoorLeft.style.width = Math.round(0.5 * width);
        divDoorLeft.style.height = height;
        divDoorLeft.style.float = "left";

        divDoorRight.style.position = "relative";
        divDoorRight.style.overflow = "hidden";
        divDoorRight.style.width = Math.round(0.5 * width);
        divDoorRight.style.height = height;
        divDoorRight.style.float = "left";
        divDoorRight.style.marginLeft = -width;

        canvas1.width = Math.round(0.5 * width);
        canvas1.height = height;
        cvContext = canvas1.getContext("2d");
        my_gradient = cvContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);
        my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "blue");
        my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
        cvContext.fillStyle = my_gradient;
        cvContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.height);

        canvas2.width = Math.round(0.5 * width);
        canvas2.height = height;
        cvContext = canvas2.getContext("2d");
        my_gradient = cvContext.createLinearGradient(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);
        my_gradient.addColorStop(0, "blue");
        my_gradient.addColorStop(1, "white");
        cvContext.fillStyle = my_gradient;
        cvContext.fillRect(0, 0, canvas2.width, canvas2.height);

        //when the user hovers over the div that contains our html...
        var d = $("divBox");
        $("divBox").hover(function () {
            //... we get the width of the div and split it by 2  ...
            var width = $(this).outerWidth() / 2;
            /*... and using that width we move the left "part" of the image to left and right "part"
            to right by changing it's indent from left side or right side... */
            $(this).find('divDoorLeft').animate({ right: width }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            $(this).find('divDoorRight').animate({ left: width }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
        }, function () {
            //... and when he hovers out we get the images back to their's starting position using the same function... '
            $(this).find('divDoorLeft').animate({ right: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            $(this).find('divDoorRight').animate({ left: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 300 });
            //... close it and that's it
        });
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="MyOnLoad()" style="width:100%; height: 100%; padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 0 0 0 0; overflow: hidden; background:#FF0000">
<div id="divBox">        
        <div id="divHolder">
            <div id="divDoorLeft"><canvas id="canvas1"/></div>
            <div id="divDoorRight"><canvas id="canvas2"/></div>

        </div>
        <div id="divUnderneath">
            Looks nice doesn't it :)
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Need some clarification to be able to help you figure this out. Which div from your code are you trying to fill, and with what? A background color, or or you trying to fill the whole div with the image? If you posted this somewhere and linked to it, I could take a look and help you troubleshoot what is up here. JsFiddle?

Comment: Arwhy, Its the underneath bit to be (ie the bit 'The text underneath') of the div id=imageHolder.

I want box_container's underneath to be completely fill the client screen of the web page. The ultimate goal is to put a load of divs in place of the 'The text underneath', which also fill the entire screen. All but one will be hidden at any one time, and the visible one will randomly change every time the door panels open.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "the text underneath" into it's own div, and use a css height or min-height attribute to get this to work.

```
<div id="underneath" style="height: 400px;">
    The text underneath
</div>
```

See this link for more info or to play with the code a bit:
[your JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fabld/8v2W4/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply darkveloper. I am away from my development pc at the moment. I am getting a Error on Page on that link you provide (and the doors dont seem to work).....Also, the main problem I am having, is not when I set to an exact value, eg 400px, but when I want it to fill the entire client area.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fabld/8v2W4/embedded/result/  might work better. You still need a div around the underneath text. Then, use style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" If that doesn't work, you may need to change the height and width of the container around the div you made for the text. When in doubt the parent is always to blame. If you could put your page up on the web somewhere, I'd love to help you get this working. Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for that. (I am still on my friend's machine. The error I was getting was because he has ie8 which does not have canvases. I temporarily installed firefox.) ??What is the best way to get the client area size in javascript code?? At the moment I can only get about half the height.

Comment: What do you mean by client size? Are you talking about the div container size, or the whole visible area of the window (usually called the viewport)? You can detect the viewport size with jQuery, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport

Comment: If you did a Hello World program, you would get the blue strip at the top, the beige areas with things like favourites, and google bars, and then you get a large white area. Its the size of that white area. I want my door panels fillng that entire white area. (I cannot seem to get my doors covering the entire height of that area - I only seem to fill about half.)

Comment: Back on my development pc. I have tried everything I can think of, including document.documentElement.clientWidth. All I can get, when fullscreen are the doors coming to about half way down. Anyone have any ideas I would be very greatful.

Comment: That white area is known as the viewport, see my previous post.