# Get the width of the viewport and apply it to a tag or class width

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have horizontal layout and it has 5 inline divs. Is there a way in javascript to get the width of the users' viewport then apply it to the each content panel tags width, so it will be 100% in every content panel? I need it to be 100% of the viewport because there are parallax elements inside it[image]

I have tried this css code below but the panels are just stacking on top of each other.

```
#contentPanel { width: 100%; float: left;}
```

I really don't know if the questions makes any sense, because I've been up for 16 hours searching and trying to work this out.

Comment: [Exact duplicate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport)

Comment: So you've got 5 divs, and you want each one to be as wide as the client viewport. But you don't want the divs to wrap. Where are the other divs supposed to go? Off the side of the screen? If so, you would have to use absolute positioning, or better yet, don't really do that. Just make it look like that's what's happening by using a JS or jQuery animation to slide the new div in and the old div out.

Comment: @Travesty3 Yes I want the other divs to go off the screen, but if I use absolute positioning, I will be using static pixel measurements where to put the 5 divs inline. Yes I've seen some gallery carousels but that is not my goal. I will use iscroll plugin so I can have a scroller that looks like from iOS. Here's a demo for the horizontal scroll: http://iscroll-js.googlecode.com/hg-history/bd496ab69c553b6e3d294c5f68200513215f5e75/examples/horizontal-scroll/index.html

Comment: The problem with iscroll is, you need a static pixel width. I want to hack the width with javascript and apply to the width of the scroller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy with JQuery:

```
var fullDiv = $("div");

var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

$("body, html").width(3*viewportWidth);
fullDiv.width(viewportWidth);
fullDiv.height(viewportHeight);
```

Simple [Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/afbtE).

You will want to update the `div`s when the browser is resized probably, currently it only works when it first loads. Read more about [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/).

Comment: This code is magic, I really tried not to post a question until I find a reasonable answers in google. But this... OH YEAH! Thank you very much. I may take a long nap or after this...
By the way is it ok to reload the page once a browser resize is detected?