# re-size text area based on window size

Tags: javascript

I have maximize button in pop window, and i have a text area and want to re-size it based on maximizing the window. below are the code for opening the pop up window

```
var url = "mypopup.do" + params;
var modalprops = "height=310px,width=400px,scrollbars=yes,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes";
window.open(url, 'winName', modalprops, false);
```

Comment: The code for opening the window is probably not relevant. Look into the `window.onresize` event.

Answer (score 7):

Give it a percentage relative width as such:

```
<textarea style="width:100%"></textarea>
```

This should resize it without javascript when the browser is resized.

**EDIT**: Both *Width* and *Height* are edited if you set them on your textarea's css:

```
<div style="width:40%;height:40%">
    <textarea style="width:100%; height:100%;"></textarea>
</div>
```

This would resize the textarea accordingly, inside the div and the underlying popup window.

**jsBin**: http://jsbin.com/odukur/1/

Comment: This would only resize it vertically. It's likely the OP means in both dimensions in `based on maximizing the window`.

Comment: Thanks Hanlet for your response. I could resize the text area width by using above but how can i adjust the height ? If i use height=100%, i get a very thin text area :(

Comment: @Pankaj, what is the size of the textarea's parent? Textarea will inherit the height from its parent.

Comment: The jsBin you linked shows a text area that is exactly two rows high. how do i make it however many rows as needed to fit the window???

Answer (score 4):

If you need to fine tune beyond Hanlet Escaño's method (which is great) and you're allowed to use jQuery, I would recommend using the `resize()` function following the general method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport) to get the size of the window and adjusting the height and width of your `textarea` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean it ?

```
<div>
    <textarea id='debug'></textarea>
    <button>Resize</button>
    <textarea id='test'>some words</textarea>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
 $("button").click(function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width() - 50; // -50 only want to show beacutiful >3
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height() - 90;
    $('#test').height(viewportHeight);
    $('#test').width(viewportWidth);
    $('#debug').text(viewportWidth + ':' + viewportHeight);
});
```

Change the 'Result' window, and click the button, you will find the textarea has been resized.

The code is simple, I think it may inspire you.

Thanks Moch Daear's tips.