# How to set div to percentage of viewport?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, less

I have to set a `<div class="row" ng-repeat="..">..</div>` to a percentage of the viewport minus a set amount of pixels (which probably won't be a problem because of jQuery or LESS). The big problem is the `ng-repeat`.

Is there a way in either jQuery, Angular or LESS to do this?

Edit: The big problem is ng-repeat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achieved without JavaScript by using [CSS calc()](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) and [CSS vw](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) unit values:

```
.row {
  width: calc(50vw - 60px);
}
```

50vw corresponds to 50% of the viewport width.

Comment: This solution is very simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Get the width/height of the viewport like in [Using jQuery To Get Size of Viewport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport)

and then do

```
var percent = 0.5;
var pixelsToSubtract = 10;
var adjustedWidth =  ($(window).width()*percent - pixelsToSubract) + 'px';
var adjustedHeight =  ($(window).height()*percent - pixelsToSubract) + 'px';
$('.row').css({width:adjustedWidth, height:adjustedHeight});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if i put usual jQuery code in a .js file and reference it on the html, it's called before angluar has gone through the `ng-repeat`. The timing is the problem.

Comment: @LukasDörig, even if you put the code in document ready like $(document).ready(function(){...});?

Comment: I'm very sorry, i missed what you did with the `.css({..});`. It works now. Thanks! I tried it with directly selecting the element, not with setting the css.