# How to get viewport size in jquery-3?

Tags: jquery, jquery-3

`$(window).height()` used to return the height of the browser viewport window, and `$(window).width()` was used for browser window width.

`$(window).height()` now just returns the same value as `$(document).height()`, i.e. the height of the whole page.

What is a proper way to acquire viewport sizes now in jquery?

Comment: according to these links http://api.jquery.com/height/, http://api.jquery.com/width/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044573/using-jquery-to-get-size-of-viewport using $(window).height() and $(window).width() is the correct way of getting the viewport.

Comment: weird, can't reproduce it anymore. indeed, those functions work fine. must have been some weird mix with bootstrap or other libraries possibly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the width and height of the viewport:

```
var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
```

resize event of the page:

```
$(window).resize(function() {

    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

});
```

Comment: thanks, indeed that works. i might blame a jquery plugin I tried to use too.

Comment: Be sure you have <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of your page or $(window).height() will return the same as $(document).height()!